# Counting number of equations for Rarita-Schwinger field (in Supergravity textbook)

Tags: fermions, spinors, gauge-invariance, degrees-of-freedom, supergravity

I am reading the book "Supergravity" by Freedman and van Proeyen (2012). On page 96, they are talking about the equation of motion of massless vector-spinor field (the spinor index is suppressed):

$$ \gamma^{\mu\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho = 0 \tag{5.3} $$

They say:

> "Gauge invariance is manifest, and the left-hand side vanishes identically when the derivative $\partial_{\mu}$ is applied. Thus (5.3) comprises $(D-1)2^{[D/2]}$ independent equations, which is enough to determine the $2^{[D/2]}D$ components of $\Psi_\rho$ up to the freedom of a gauge transformation."

I don't understand the counting as how do they get $(D-1)2^{[D/2]}$ independent equations. Here is my attempt:

(5.3) is equivalent to these equations:
$$ \gamma^{0\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho = 0, \gamma^{1\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho = 0 ,\ ......\ , \gamma^{(D-1)\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho = 0.  $$
These are $D$ equations, and each equation has a hidden spinor index taking $2^{[D/2]}$ values. So in total, we have $D*2^{[D/2]}$ equations.

Hitting with $\partial_{\mu}$ gives:

$$ \partial_0 \gamma^{0\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho + \partial_1 \gamma^{1\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho + ... + \partial_{(D-1)} \gamma^{(D-1)\nu\rho} \partial_{\nu} \Psi_\rho = 0 $$

But this already follows from the previous equations. So this doesn't change the number of independent equations.

So, what I am doing wrong here? How to get the correct number of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freedman & van Proeyen are counting off-shell DOF$ =n(D-1)$ of $\Psi_{\mu}$, i.e. they subtract the $n$ gauge transformations
$$ \Psi_{\mu}(x)~\longrightarrow~\Psi_{\mu}(x) +\partial_{\mu}\epsilon(x) \tag{5.1} ,$$

where $n=2^{[D/2]}$ is the number of spinor components.